# iOS 11 MapView Compass under NavigationBar and SafeArea not working on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, layout, android-mapview, safearealayoutguide

I'm struggling with migrating my App to iOS 11. For reusability I split my hierarchy into multiple StoryBoards. In the first StoryBoard I have a custom container view controller which hosts a tab bar and a special view (MonitoringView). It is embedded in a UINavigationController. I embed this controller in a navigation controller because I want the same functionality and title on all tabs.

[image]

In one of the tabs I want to display a map. On the StoryBoard I pinned the map to the SuperView with 0 so I get it under the navigation and tab bar. Here I also have a custom control which I pinned to the SafeArea of the view controller.

[image]

Now when I run the app, i use

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    controller.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(monitoringView.frame.size.height, 0, tabBar.frame.size.height, 0)
}
```

in the container controller to adjust the safe area insets of the child controller (the one with the map).

While this works fine for the extra control which I pinned to the safe area, the compass and legal notice of the map are hidden under the navigation/tabbar on iOS 11. On iOS 10 though the control is under the bar while the notice and compass are to far to the center of the view

[image]

I am looking for a solution for days now and I tried so many different things. I'm really desperate and have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to set `automaticallyAdjustsContentInset` to YES or NO.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can easily rewrite from Objective-C to Swift.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 11)
{
    MKCompassButton *Compass = [MKCompassButton compassButtonWithMapView:self.mapView];
    Compass.frame = CGRectMake(ScreenW - 45, 90, Compass.frame.size.width, Compass.frame.size.height);
    //Compass.compassVisibility = MKFeatureVisibilityVisible;
    [self.view addSubview:Compass];
    self.mapView.showsCompass = NO;
```

}